# Devexpress Reports and DBContext Datasource

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am using Devexpress in VS2013. i want to know how can I use my entity framework classes as data source in Devexpress reports(XtraReport). e.g I have a DBset "Employs" in my my DBcontext how can i use it in Xtrareport Data source,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily bind the report to the EF query result if you convert your query to the `List` and then bind your report to this List:

```
report.DataSource = (from employee in DbContext.Employees
                    select employee).ToList();
```

I believe the following KB article will be helpful:
[How to create a master-detail report bound to an ORM (Entity Framework) model in MVC applications](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E5059)

Comment: Yes it is Amazingly Easy. Just drop Bindingsource control on Xtrareport and on initialize report I put Your coding. Working Like a charm...Thnaks alot